# Notation for the Covariant Derivative of a smooth section in the direction of a tangent vector X

Tags: differential-geometry

So I am trying to convince myself of a proof found in lecture concerning the curvature matrix. The idea is I have a theorem stating that:

For X,Y $\in \mathfrak X(M)$ (space of smooth vector fields on M). Then:
$$R(X,Y) = [\nabla_X,\nabla_Y]-\nabla_{[X,Y]} $$

In order to do this we need the definition of the induced linear map R given (in our course) by the curvature matrix:
$$R(X,Y)|_U (s) = \Omega^i_{\; j}(X,Y)|_U s^j$$

Where $s=(s^1, \dots, s^n)$ are smooth sections over a local trivialization $(U,\Phi_U)$. In our lecture we have that:
$$\Omega = dA + A \wedge A$$
and
$$A^i_{\;j} = \Gamma^i_{\; jk}dx^k$$

Where we use that A is the connection matrix, and the gammas are the connection coefficients (here A is written in terms of a local trivialization). The problem I have is when it comes down to doing the work to show that each side is equal, I come upon the quantity
$$\nabla_X s = \langle \nabla s , X \rangle$$

in the notes. The covariant derivative of the smooth section is given by
$$\nabla s |_U =(\frac{\partial s^i}{\partial x^k} + \Gamma^i_{\; jk}s^j )dx^k\otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial u^i}$$

where $u=(u^1, \dots,u^n)$ are the coordinates over the local trivialization. When I look at the quantity in angled brackets, the physicist in me wants to assume an inner product, but I am unsure how to treat that object or what it is. I read a passage in Chern, Chen, Lam "Lectures on Differential Geometry" where the author asserts that the angled bracket quantity "...represents the pairing between TM and T*M." and gives no real clue how to find it, at least in notation that I am use to. If anyone can provide a little insight I would be thankful. If anyone needs further explanation of the notation I use in lecture feel free to ask.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a 1-form and $v$ a vector field, then does the notation $\langle \alpha, v\rangle$ make sense to you?

Comment: Unfortunately no it doesn't mean anything to me, even the person I talked to who supplies these lectures realized they should have been slightly more explicit in their explanation of the term. But I have found my own answer to this question and have almost no more difficulty with this proof. I don't really want to answer my own question but it would be nice if it was closed from further answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the expression I was looking for, after some discussion with the person that provides the lecture, is given by:

$$ \langle \nabla s , X \rangle = (\frac{ds^i}{dt} + \Gamma^i_{\;jk}s^j X^k(t) )\frac{\partial}{\partial u^i} $$

Answer (score 0):

this is a directly definition of Riemannian connection or named Levi-Civita connection !

see wiki :

1. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_connection_on_a_surface
2. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection

and i also find two paper for you :

1. http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~kapovich/481-07/riem.pdf
2. http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/cis61008Riem-conn.pdf